# Streaming job vs looped batch job for consuming data from Kafka queue

Tags: java, loops, apache-kafka, streaming, kafka-consumer-api

For example, if I have a Java application that is always running and it's reading data from a Kafka queue as it arrives, with the purpose of getting data and forwarding it to a db...  Is there any major downside to infinitely looping through a batch-job rather than doing it through Kafka Streaming/Kafka Connect?  Considering I'm not pointlessly creating or wasting resources each loop and that I'm handling the multithreading properly, are there any major downsides or reasons not to do this?  Is it a viable option for a long running application?

(I have reasons for not using Kafka Streams/Connect with our use case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I talked to my staff engineer.  It turns out that it is a viable option to do an infinite loop through a batch job as long as you're doing it correctly.  Meaning you've fine tuned the configuration, your pausing briefly between loops, and you're properly handling the life of any connections/consumers/producers if they were to fail.  Another team is already doing it in prod environment.